Driving relay without a control Fet: Back EMF consideration when control side is Grounded
I want to drive a G8G-1SV DC24 relay just by turning on/off its control side with 24V like this:

while following the recommendation from its datasheet for the back-emf protection:

My consideration is that, the control side of the relay (the coil) connects to the GND and that would stop the voltage from rising to 25V and activating the TVS diode, while the voltage at "24V REL" will keep decreasing to minus whatever voltage the coil tries to reach, maybe -100V.

So it won't be possible for the voltage at the GND point of the coil to get to 25V and activate the TVS diode?
Or will the GND voltage reach 25V close to the coil there on my layout/copper and then the TVS will be activated?
Overall, what will be the voltage at the GND of the coil when the "24V REL" goes from 24V to GND?


The GND will stay 0 V unless you have multiple connections that can cause a high drop therefore a non-zero (substantial) potential difference across all the 0V connections.
The relay coil is an inductor. By its nature, it doesn't allow the current flow to be stopped instantly, so it'll react to this by increasing/decreasing the voltage at the cut-end. This is called "flyback action".
You plan to drive the relay by switching positive voltage to the coil:

When the switch is closed, \$v_L\$ is equal to your 24 V voltage (assuming negligible drop across the switch).
When the switch opens, the current flow through the inductor (relay coil for your case) will not stop instantly. To imagine easier what will happen, consider the following figure:

The current \$di\$ is the instant change in current. For example, a drop in current from, say, 50 mA to zero in 1 nanoseconds. This current will drop a significant voltage across the large, imaginary parallel resistor (the orange one in the figure). Therefore, the - end of the \$v_L\$ voltage will be much greater than the + end. Because the - end of the inductor is already 0 V, the + end will go further negative, causing the effective voltage across the switch much greater than 24V.
Same can be found from the inductor's current-voltage relationship:
$$
v_L=L \ \frac{di}{dt} = L \ \frac{-50 \ 10^{-3}}{1\ 10^{-9}}<<0 \ \text{V}
$$
So, if you place the D-TVS network as shown in your schematic, it'll limit the voltage at 24V REL node to about -25 V which makes the voltage across the switch about 24-(-25)=~50 V.
So, if a high-side semiconductor switch is used to drive the relay then it should withstand ~50 V. But you may ditch the TVS and clamp with the diode only:


Right! If a switch is used there, the voltage on the High side of the switch will be 24V while on the other side (the relay) the voltage will drop to -25V so it needs to withstand ~50V!

@ChristianidisVasilis yes. We are assuming the TVS's clamp voltage to be 25V but could be higher or lower depending on the waveform of the current.

With high side switched relays the A1 terminal (relay positive) will go negative on power off due to the inductance. Current remains flowing until energy is dissipated.
So in your case A+ will go down to -35 Volt due to the clamping limits of a TVS diode.
Can your high side switch handle this?
I suggest you remove the TVS diode, in most cases you don't need it.
The single diode will shunt the current and there will not be a surge larger than the forward voltage of the diode.
The TVS diode is only there to decrease the turn-off-time. If you do not have strict turn-off requirements and stay well within relay switching limits it is not needed.

(you mean -25V, not -35V). Also thank you, both answers are useful!

@ChristianidisVasilis No, the rated and clamping voltage of those diodes is not the same.

I think I got it. The point where the coil connects to the GND might not be able to rise to 24V, but since the "24V REL" net will drop to 0V and keep decreasing, once it reaches -25V, the D4 will already be conducting and the TVS will activate.

So the difference with having a Fet on the low side would be, that the "24V REL" voltage would not need to drop so low in voltage (at -25V) to activate the TVS diode.
